# Javascript define private variable

Tags: javascript, private

I want to build a class using javascript like in c, the main problem is `private` attribute.

```
var tree = {
  private_var: 5,
  getPrivate:function(){
   return this.private_var;
  }
};
console.log(tree.private_var);//5 this line want to return unaccessible
console.log(tree.getPrivate());//5
```

so I want to detect the access from `tree.private_var` and return `unaccessible`, and `this.private_var` return `5`.
My question is: Is there any way to set private attribute in javascript?

EDIT: I saw this way

```
class Countdown {
    constructor(counter, action) {
        this._counter = counter;
        this._action = action;
    }
    dec() {
        if (this._counter < 1) return;
        this._counter--;
        if (this._counter === 0) {
            this._action();
        }
    }
}
CountDown a;
```

`a._counter` is not accessible?
but

Comment: But what? It looks like you didn't finish the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define `tree` as a function instead of JavaScript object, define private variable in the function by `var` keyword, define public getting function by `this.` keyword and create a new instance by using the function

```
var Tree = function(){
    var private_var = 5;
    this.getPrivate = function(){
        return private_var;
    }
}

var test = new Tree();
test.private_var; //return undefined
test.getPrivate(); //return 5
```

In ES6, you can do this but it is **not supported by IE** so I wouldn't recommend

```
class Tree{
    constructor(){
        var private_var =5;
        this.getPrivate = function(){ return private_var }

    }
}

var test = new Tree();
test.private_var; //return undefined
test.getPrivate(); //return 5
```

Comment: You don't show how to do it using ES6 class syntax.

Comment: Thanks @SolomonTam, defining class that way will be good in javascript.

Comment: `so I wouldn't recommend`?`so I would recommend`